# Ajax Get method returns NaN as a result of error

Tags: php, ajax

What I am trying to do is get users email and pass it to subdomain.domain.com/index.php from sidebar of wordpress (user subscription process). The php file has only three 'echo' if email already exist then 'subscribe is echoed' , if new then 'success' and finally 'error'. I am wondering why does 'NaN' results form the php file.

I also tried to alert 'data' in success function but success never alerts. But the php file runs inserts data into database and users also get email. its just that response gives NaN.

Note: This entire process works on my localhost (WAMP SERVER).

My Ajax code:

```
$("#jap_news_sub_button").click(function() {        
    var user_email = $("#jap_news_sub_email").val();
var datastring = "email=" + user_email;
    $('.img_loader').show();
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://subdomain.domain.com/index.php",
        type: "get",
        data: datastring,
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(data) {
          if (data == "success") {
                $('#jap_error').fadeOut(100);
                $('#jap_response').fadeIn(100);
                $('.img_loader').hide();
                $('.jap_news_sub').fadeOut(100);
            } else if (data == "subscribed") {
                $('#jap_error').fadeOut(100);
                $('.jap_news_sub').fadeOut(100);
                $('.img_loader').hide();
                $('#jap_response').html('You are already subscribed.').fadeIn(100);
            } else {
                $('.img_loader').hide();
                $('#jap_error').fadeOut(100);
            }
        },
        error: function(edata) {
            alert(edata.a + edata.b);
        }
    });
    return false;
    }
    else {
    $('#jap_error').fadeIn(100);
});
```

});

The PHP file

```
 include("connect.php");

 $email = $_GET['email'];

 $query = mysql_query("select * from jap_wysija_user where email='$email' and status='1'");

if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0)

echo 'subscribed';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`error: function(xhr,status,error){` instead of `error: function(edata) {`

error: - A function to run if the request fails.

```
error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
    alert("Status: " + textStatus + "Error: " + errorThrown); 
}
```

Comment: Chinnu i tried your method I now get the following error

Status: parsererrorError
Error : jQuery11020158450982067734_1384774506860 was not called